# PHP PECL Threads results order

Tags: php, multithreading, pecl

I have a multithread, the main idea is to run nmap commands in the console and deliver the results in an orderly manner,

example:

Results after shell_exec

Command 4
Command 1
Command 2
Command 3

How can I get the results in an orderly manner?

Command 1
Command 2
Command 3
Command 4

```
public function __construct($arg) {
    $this->arg = $arg;
}

public function run() {     

        $salida = shell_exec($comando);         

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you're launching them in separate threads, the jobs are unlikely to finish in the same order that they were started. You'll need to track them and wait until all are done. You didn't include much of your code, but here's a generic example:

```
// create jobs
$jobs[0] = new nmapJob(args0);
$jobs[1] = new nmapJob(args1);
...

// start jobs
foreach ($jobs as $job)
{
  $job.start();
}

// wait for jobs to finish
foreach ($jobs as $job)
{
  $job.join();
}

// display results
foreach ($jobs as $job)
{
  echo($job.salida);
}
```

But... I suggest using a different technique. Having a shell command dangle like that isn't the best of practices, especially if it can take a while to run (as nmap jobs often do). It's more complicated, but look into running the scans asynchronously. Spawn them as a separate process and have the results dumped into a directory. A different PHP script can be used to process the results in that directory once the scans are done.